# jQuery fancybox stuck on spinning loader

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I am implementing the ajax example for jQuery fancybox, but all I seem to get is the spinning loader when I point it to a php file and echo a message. It works fine reading the ajax.txt.

I do not have much experience with ajax so I am sure I am missing something simple.

Update: I have gotten a little closer to the issue. I have found it to work in chrome but not firefox 10, still not sure what is causing it as I dont get an error - ok in ie9 also

**New update: I have identified the problem. It was adblocker. I tried it on another two machines, both with chrome. The only difference was on was running adblock.
Is this always going to be an issue with ajax or is there something I can do in the code?**

```
    $(document).ready( function() {


        $("#various2").fancybox();

    });

    <a id="various2" href="adContent.php">
```

Php file:

```
<?php

    echo "Hello"; 

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your actual php code, do you have your

```
<a href="..."
```

tag well formed?  According to the sample above, you don't, so it may be that jQuery can't properly parse the document to get your tag.  Are there any errors coming up in IE or FireFox (with FireBug enabled) that you can provide?

Comment: Yes my php is in the same location as the .txt file which worked. No errors in the firebug console. It doesn't seem to be loading the file as would normal happen in the console

Comment: What happens when you navigate directly to the php file, are you getting anything back?  Also, is this the correct naming of the file, inclusive of capitalization: "adContent.php"

Comment: Checked that alright, I have found the issue to be adblocker for Firefox and chrome. If I disable it ajax is now fine. I dont have this issue with any other ajax function. Just the one with fancybox. Could be an issue with the way it is encoded? It works fine loading a .txt but not with .php. I am really unsure of this area of json etc.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the content type to ajax.

```
$("#various2").fancybox({type:'ajax'});
```

Comment: Tried that already Adrian, but it did not work. I have put it back in anyway as it should be there. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Silly question, but do you have the required jquery links in your head?

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript" src="[Your library loc]/jquery.min.js"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript" src="[Your library loc]/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"> </script>
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="[Your library loc]/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
> ```

Comment: Not so silly, I have been known to forget the basics. Not in this case though. It does work when I call the ajax.txt. So all good to that point. Should probably mention also that I have tested the php file direct and it does echo out, so that is ok also.

Comment: Did you try entering the script path into your browser, and see if it is coming up?

I had that once where my admin failed to allow my script directory to allow anonymous access.

Comment: No luck with that either I'm afraid. Again it does not show up in the firebug console as a get request. It it was a file location issue it would show as an error

Comment: That was my best shot, because on my server, the js content was replaced with a 401 message.
Can you post your Apache version info? I'll see if I can replicate on one of my boxes.

Comment: Thanks, would appreciate it. Apache version 2.2.22 PHP version  5.3.10

Comment: It have gotten a little closer to the issue. I have found it to work in chrome but not firefox 10, still not sure what is causing it as I dont get an error - ok in ie9 also

Comment: I still haven't tried FF10. However, I know there are tools to disable scripting on FF10. Do other scripts run in FF10 for you?